# Does twitter4j provide the capability to search tweets between 2 dates

Tags: java, twitter4j

Does twitter4j provide the capability to search tweets between 2 dates (e.g. 2011-10-27 05:30:00 to 2011-10-27 06:30:00)

currently it seems to have the granularity of a date and not hours or minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at the current version there is no way to specify date & time for searching within given range.

And that's the limitation of [Twitter search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search):

> ## Notes about Search Operators
>
> ### since and until
>
> - do not support the negation (-) operator.
> - **List item should be entered in the format year-month-day or yyyy-mm-dd.**
> - **are assumed to be from/to 00:00 UTC.**
> - cannot be set into the future. If until is in the future you will receive an HTTP 403 error with the message: `{"error":"You cannot use an 'until:' date in the future"}`. If since is in the future you will receive an HTTP 403 error with the message: `{"error":"since_id too recent, poll less frequently"}`

Answer (score 2):

```
Query query=new Query("#sachin");

//Returns tweets with since the given date.  Date should be formatted as YYYY-MM-DD 

query.setSince("2012-02-20");
```

Answer (score 0):

query.since() works only going back a couple of days, a week or so, not more. I think the only option is to use a screen scraper.