# Access 7 days tweets

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I want to get 7 days tweets from twitter and this is my code below:

```
     for(int i=1;i<16;i++)
    {
    Query qy = new Query();
    qy.setRpp(100);
    qy.setPage(i);
    qy.resultType("Mixed");

    QueryResult result = twitter.search(qy);
    List<Tweet> tweets = result.getTweets();
```

}

I got some tweets using twitter4j but I could not control the time of the tweets. I want to get tweets for only 7 days, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

- If you want 7 days prior to current date, you can use this option

  qy.setSince("[YOUR DATE]")
- If you want 7 days ahead, try the Twitter Streaming API:
  https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview
- If you want to search between two particular date, Twitter Search does not provide a way to do this but you could "filter" it out using Timestamp of tweets.

[Does twitter4j provide the capability to search tweets between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915634/does-twitter4j-provide-the-capability-to-search-tweets-between-2-dates)